# How to integrate google maps pin with form in AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-grape

I'm going to allow create pins to google map by users. Those pins will be visible for every logged users. How to do that using form and input with geocode? Maybe AngularJS? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking how to create the pin, or show all of the pins to everyone that is logged in?

Comment: At first: I want to allow logged users to create a pin. All pins will be shown for all logged users on common map.

Comment: Okay, so what part of that do you need help with? You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: What's the best way to get it? What type of googleAPI should I use?